# Change the content of an anchor tag using CSS

Tags: html, css, anchor

I would like to change the content of an anchor tag using CSS. Below is the HTML of the anchor tag:

```
<a class="search"><img src="/search.png" id="searchImg"></a>
```

The anchor tag has an image in it, I would like to replace it with text using CSS. I cannot change the HTML as I do not have access to it. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: **Please don't do this**...the `content` property is not for actual content, it's for styling purposes and it's terrible for accessibility.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code and explain **why** you feel the need to do this.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question, also had given the HTML example.

Comment: Do you have the current CSS as well? I highly recommend you **not** doing this. If you need **fundamental** changes to HTML, you should be granted access....attempting such **hacky** methods to get round access issues in ridiculous ***especially*** since you have access to the CSS files

Comment: Well, you could hide the image (something like `display: none`) and then add content using pseudo elements but I echo Paulie_D's points.

Comment: I should also mention that it looks like you're using an anchor link with **no `href``**...so I'm assuming this is some kind of button - [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely **must** do this and my comments pretty much cover why you shouldn't... it is possible but **not recommended**.

In order to maintain *any* current accessibility it seems to me that you want to hide the image **visually** but retain it's location and size.

Hence:

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* for visiual cue */
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.search img {
  opacity: 0;
  /* just hide it visually but leave it in place */
  display: block;
}
.search::before {
  content: "Searching";
  position: absolute;
  /* position the pseudo-element over the image with the same dimenesions */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="search">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-25-6.jpg" id="searchImg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. If you REALLY cannot access the HTML source, the only workable solution I can think of is to generate a `pseudo` element that covers the image, which displays the text.

```
/* hide the image on hover */
.search:hover #searchImg {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* show a pseudo element inside the anchor */
.search:hover {
    position: relative;
}
.search:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    content: "Some text to display";
}
```

**This is not a very good solution at all.** I would rather have a hidden element with the text inside the anchor, that toggles display-status, or just use JavaScript...

Comment: I don't think this is a **hover** situation, it's general replacement.

Comment: Then OP is pretty fudged.

Comment: Not really...I'm against it but see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the help of jQuery

```js
 $("search").text("your text");
```